# @Path and regular expression (Jersey/REST)

Tags: java, regex, rest, jersey

I'm using **Jersey** in a **REST** project and I'm needing to use **regular expression**.

Digging about it is simple like:

```
@Path("/resources")
public class MyResource {

   @GET
   @Path("{subResources:.*}")
   public String get(@PathParam("subResources") String subResources) {...}
}
```

But, doing like this, the method is getting the request **only** if I passes 1 param, example:

> > GET: .../resources/firstSubResource

If I use more then 1 parameter the method is **not** getting the request, example:

> > GET: .../resources/firstSubResource/seccondSubResource/thirdSubResource

---

I'm only capable of using regex if in my @Path contains a **variable** or **text value**, example:

```
@Path("{SubResource1}/{subResources:.*}")
```

Or

```
@Path("/hardCodeString/{subResources:.*}")
```

Today I could run with this solution of a variable, but is not oK for my perspective.

---

My web.xml

```xml
(...)
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myproject.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/1.0/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
(...)
```

---

**Question**

- Does anyone have worked with something related?
- I'm doing something wrong?
- I think that this could be a bug, when working with more then one @Path, one in the Class and other in the Method.
- Any tips is appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Would you please post more information including: the <servlet> and <servlet-mapping> tags from `web.xml`, sample URLs, the @Path annotation that matched each sample URL, and all values of path parameters that Jersey received? (Edit your question to add this info.)

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks for your answer, I add some more information to the question. Regards!

Answer (score 21):

Can you try using regular expression as given in [Overview of JAX-RS 1.1](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/jax-rs.html#d4e102)

Code snippet would look as below for your case

```
@Path("resources/")
public class MyResource {

   @GET
   @Path("{subResources: [a-zA-Z0-9_/]+}")
   public String get(@PathParam("subResources") String subResources) {...}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you want to match any characters after "resources/", use the pattern `.+`, for example, `@Path("{subResources: .+}")`, as the above wont match urls with spaces or periods in the. For example "/resources/test/me.jpg" wouldn't match.

Comment: and one more slight modification - if you want to ensure that & isn't included in the `subResources` part, use the `[^&?]` pattern instead of `.+`

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a really old question, but I just came across it whilst trying looking for the solution for myself. Im trying to accept s3 style filenames, eg /folder/whatever/blah/.../image.jpg that could be of any conceivable length and contain many `/`s.

Anyway your own solution:

```
@Path("/hardCodeString/{subResources:.*}")
```

Gave me an idea... turns out this works:

```
@Path("/{subResources:.*}")
```

notice the initial `/`. Now maybe in three years this is something that they've fixed or whatever, but I hope this helps someone as this page seems to be the only place that mentions this predicament.

Answer (score 7):

Can you try removing your *@PathParam* annotation and instead get the path by *UriInfo*:

```
@Context UriInfo uriInfo;

@GET
@Path("{subResources:.*}")
public String get() 
{
    String path = uriInfo.getPath();
}
```

I don't know why but it works in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be opposed to accepting a single PathParam, representing a collection of subResources delimited by some token?

For example ...

```
@Path("/resources)
public class MyResource {

   @GET
   @Path("{subResources}")
   public String get(@PathParam("subResources") String subResources) 
   {
      String[] params = StringUtils.split(subResources, ";");
   }
}
```

.. should handle

```
GET: .../resources/firstSubResource
&
GET: .../resources/firstSubResource;seccondSubResource;thirdSubResource
```