# How to proxy a request to another location with enriched header in a java EE application

Tags: java, java-ee-6, netflix-zuul

I'm facing the following problem.  I need to create a way in a java EE application running on websphere (without Spring) to proxy a request to another location and enrich the header with a bearer token.

take following example

> GET request: http://servicehost.com/proxy/targetapi/userresource

needs to be forwarded to

> GET request: http://othertargethost.com/targetapi/userresource with Authorization: Bearer randomtoken

I solved this problem in another application but this was a spring boot application using Netflix Zuul and spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul.

However now I'm in a strict EE context no spring allowed at all.  I have not found any good documentation or examples on how to setup or configure netflix zuul in a pure EE context.

Which other alternatives do I have to solve this problem ?  I was thinking on the following

- Setup a Servlet on **/proxy/* and create a filter that will do the forwarding
- Search the internet for something akin to Zuul with better documentation to run it in EE
- ...

I could really appreciate anything pointing me in the right direction.

[Jersey web service proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364462/jersey-web-service-proxy) is not a solution for me since this is pinpointed on a specific endpoint and with a specific http method

> GET request: http://servicehost.com/proxy/targetapi/userresource

could be

> GET request: http://servicehost.com/proxy/targetapi/contractresource

or

> GET request: http://servicehost.com/proxy/specialapi/userresource

and it needs to be able to handle GET, POST, PUT and DELETE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jersey web service proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364462/jersey-web-service-proxy)

Comment: No this will not help since this is only for a specific endpoint it needs to be more generic.  http://servicehost.com/proxy/targetapi/userresource could be http://servicehost.com/proxy/specialapi/contractresource and it needs to be able to handle GET, PUT, POST and DELETE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to use Zuul in EE so I only had one recourse and that is write my own servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "ProxyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/proxy/*"})
public class ProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String SESSION_ID_PARAM = "delijnSessionId";

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private ProxyProperties proxyProperties;

    @Inject
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Inject
    private ProxyHttpClientFactory proxyHttpClientFactory;

    @Inject
    private StreamUtils streamUtils;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        proxy(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        proxy(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        proxy(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        proxy(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private void proxy(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            String requestUrl = request.getRequestURI();
            String method = request.getMethod();
            String sessionId = getSessionId(request);

            String protocol = proxyProperties.getProperty(ProxyProperties.PROXY_PROTOCOL);
            String server = proxyProperties.getProperty(ProxyProperties.PROXY_SERVER);
            String port = proxyProperties.getProperty(ProxyProperties.PROXY_PORT);

            String newPath = requestUrl.replaceFirst(".*/proxy", "");

            URI uri = new URI(protocol, null, server, Integer.parseInt(port), newPath, request.getQueryString(), null);

            ProxyHttpMethod proxyRequest = new ProxyHttpMethod(method);
            proxyRequest.setURI(uri);
            copyBodyFromRequest(request, method, proxyRequest);
            copyHeadersFromRequest(request, proxyRequest);
            enrichWithAccessToken(proxyRequest, sessionId);

            try (CloseableHttpClient client = proxyHttpClientFactory.produce()) {
                logger.info("uri [{}]", uri);
                logger.info("method [{}]", method);
                execute(client, proxyRequest, response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new TechnicalException(e);
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
            throw new TechnicalException(e);
        }
    }

    private void execute(CloseableHttpClient client, ProxyHttpMethod proxyHttpMethod, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try (CloseableHttpResponse proxyResponse = client.execute(proxyHttpMethod)) {
            int statusCode = proxyResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode >= 200 || statusCode < 300) {
                response.setStatus(statusCode);
                HttpEntity entity = proxyResponse.getEntity();
                if(entity != null){
                    String result = streamUtils.getStringFromStream(entity.getContent());
                    logger.trace("result [" + result + "]");
                    response.getWriter().write(result);
                    response.getWriter().flush();
                    response.getWriter().close();
                }
            } else {
                throw new TechnicalException("[" + statusCode + "] Error retrieving access token");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new TechnicalException(e);
        }
    }

    private void enrichWithAccessToken(ProxyHttpMethod proxyRequest, String sessionId) {
        Optional<TokenDto> token = securityService.findTokenBySessionIdWithRefresh(sessionId);
        if (token.isPresent()) {
            String accessToken = token.get().getAccessToken();
            logger.trace(String.format("Enriching headers with: Authorization Bearer %s", accessToken));
            proxyRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        } else {
            logger.info(String.format("No token found in repository for sessionId [%s]", sessionId));
            throw new RuntimeException("No token found in repository");
        }
    }

    private void copyBodyFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String method, ProxyHttpMethod proxyRequest) throws IOException {
        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(method) || "PUT".equalsIgnoreCase(method)) {
            String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body);
            proxyRequest.setEntity(entity);
        }
    }

    private void copyHeadersFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request, ProxyHttpMethod proxyRequest) {
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            if (!"host".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName) && !"Content-Length".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
                proxyRequest.setHeader(headerName, request.getHeader(headerName));
            }
        }
    }

    private String getSessionId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String sessionId = "";
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies != null){
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (SESSION_ID_PARAM.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    sessionId = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
            return sessionId;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

not ideal but I didn't see another way out

Comment: Thank you. I needed to dynamically calculate hmac 256 signatures for outgoing/proxy requests and used this as the base/inspiration for an abstract proxy servlet with the default java httpclient.