# Jersey how to support any path param and not get 404 error

Tags: java, jersey

I have following resource defined using jersey.

```
@GET
@Path("/resource/{param1}/{param2}/functions/{name}")
```

The above will work great if {name} is simple. But I have cases when {name} can be of type "test/name1". When I have such name I get 404 error as jersey cannot find correct endpoint to support this.

How can I fix this?

thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: try `@Path("/resource/{param1}/{param2}/functions/{name : .+}")`

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2945947/6413377).